# Sitecore_master_index has stopped updating in Solr

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore

We are using Solr, hosted on Tomcat, with Sitecore 8.0. We are having an odd issue where sitecore_master_index incrementally updates an index for about half an hour after Tomcat or server start but then stops the indexing after that. This has been the case for the last 4 days now.

In the crawling logs for Sitecore there are never any entries found related to sitecore_master_index but other indexes including sitecore_core_index and sitecore_web_index get updated. Entries for the latter indexes appear in the crawling logs.

I have checked everything including the eventqueue tables size, index update strategy (which is syncmaster), indexing not paused, etc. but there is no obvious answer to this puzzle.

Any clues where to look?

Comment: `syncmaster` strategy simple hooks into item events (`item:updated`, 'item:moved`, `item:versionadded` etc). Simplest way of checking what's happening? Use some reflector to copy its code and create your own class with some logging information to check if the events are still fired. You can also debug this new code (or google about debugging Sitecore own code).

Comment: I came across something similar the other day but it was only in a particular environment. When you try to rebuild the index do you get a queued message? I tried a few things on this blog but couldn't get to the bottom of it maybe this might help - https://sitecorepm.wordpress.com/2014/05/07/how-to-fix-that-burning-smell-coming-from-your-sitecore-search-index/

Comment: As far as I could understand, you have a single index failing however Tomcat or Solr stops right after their start. I've experienced something similar on my Solr environment and what I did is stop the Sitecore instance completely (including the AppPool associated to) on IIS and stop Tomcat and Solr, then start both Tomcat and Solr, wait for a few minutes and keep an eye if the service stops, if not then back to IIS and start the Sitecore instance. Hope that helps. Cheers, Vinicius